# JavaScript window global object

Tags: javascript, object, window

I have learned that the *'window' global object* is the top-level object. It is the "box" of all the code and it contains the DOM, BOM, and the JavaScript code.

I have learned that the *window* object represents an open window in a browser, and also that the window object has no constructor which means I can't create its instance.

I have learned that the object is automatically created by the browser. How?

I mean if it doesn't have any constructor, so the browser can't create its own instance to the object, I was thinking that the browser must be able to in some way create it, so how does the browser create it?

Comment: Your reasoning is not completely correct. `window.constructor !== undefined`. Also, `window` does not contain all "the JS".

Answer (score 0):

No constructor?

```
>> window.constructor
[object Window]
```

Well, what do you know, a constructor!

That said...

```
>> new Window
(X) Object does not support this action
```

So I guess that means only native code can create new instances of [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Comment: Can you explain your self better please, when you are using constructor with the window object its returns the window object but the same can happen if i write the $this var inside a func example:function foo(){document.write($this);} if ill run the func the same thing will happen, ill be happy if u can explain what you sayed with another words pls

Comment: What else is there to explain? `window` has a constructor, that's what you're asking... right?

Comment: so if i understand correct, there is a window object he has a constructor the only way to recreate the window object is by referring it to his native code window.constructor , and i understand that we cant construct the window object into an x object we only can call him or recreate it ill happy if some one will confirm this thank u all.