# Understanding the 'window' object

Tags: javascript, object, window

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [JS Window Global Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035771/js-window-global-object)

How does the `window` object work?

I know that it is the top-level object there is and that the `window` object represents an open window in a browser.

I know that it has all object properties and methods. I have been told it can be recreated by calling the `window.constructor` and get its native code, and also that's the only way to get an instance of the object.

What is some more information about it?

Comment: I already gave you an answer to this question. Why are you asking the same question again?

Answer (score 4):

The `window` object is effectively two things:

1. The global object for browser-based JavaScript. All of the native objects and methods (`Array`, `String`, `setTimeout()`) and anything you declare outside of any function's scope goes in the `window` object. To test this, try opening a JavaScript console and checking this out:

   ```
   window.String === String
   // Returns true
   ```
2. The `window` object also deals with the browser window. `window.innerWidth` is the window's width; `window.onresize` is a function that is triggered on the window resize. Because it's the "topmost" object, you can also say things like `innerWidth` to get the window's width.

In general, it's a good practice to refer to write `window.location` instead of just `location`. Even though they'll work a lot of the time, you'll sometimes run into situations like this (which you don't want!):

```
function something() {
    var location = 'the moon';
    location.reload();    // Should be window.location.reload()
}
```

In the above example, you might've meant to refresh `window.location` instead of the `location` scoped inside this function.

And that's the window object!